# Will assets folder affect angular performance?

Tags: angular, svg, assets, angular15, image-optimization

I have a project with Angular 16. It was assumed to have more than 100 SVG files in my assets folder. I'm sure that it will increase bundle size, but I'm not sure if it will affect the performance of the application.  My question is: how do I handle this asset folder and SVG loading in the browser?

Comment: Assets folder are copied as-is when you build your application. I'm assuming that you're not explicitly asking for all the 100 svg files at once, then it wont slow down the browser

Comment: I have a game which includes thousands of small sprites stored in the assets folder and it runs fine since they don't all get pulled in at once when the game loads.